# Pass arguments to docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using version 3 of docker-compose.

```
docker-compose build MY_ARGUMENT=herro
```

How do I use this in the `docker-compose.yml` file?

States here https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/ that it is possible ([ARGS...]) but doesn't say anything else.

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

```
web:
environment:
- username=root
```

or you can specifiy a file

```
env_file:
 - ./Docker/api/api.env
```

or for just args

```
  args:
    buildno: 1
```

EXAMPLE 1

```
build: ./dir

   build:
    context: ./dir
    dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate
    args:
      buildno: 1
```